# Is Ubuntu 12.04 still stable today?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 in my HP Pavilion g6-1030se laptop, but I have a problem in developing java games. My laptop became slow. Is it ok if i go back to Ubuntu 12.04? Is it still stable today?

Comment: You have a problem, don't tell us what it is, you wanna do something else. This may be worth reading: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 12.04 is still stable, and will be fully supported and updated until April 2017